# I don't know how to get a solution to this differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I work on this equation I don't know how to get some a solution from second part becuase it just gives me some unknown lines, first part is easy and I just put it for next part.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {y'[x] + (3 a)/(2 x) y[x] + ((3/2 a - 1) k)/(y[x] x^3) - b/(
 2 y[x] x) == 0};
sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[eqns, y[x], x]]
(* y1 is the second solution in sol *)
y1[x_] = Sqrt[-( k /x^2) + b/(3 a) + x^(-3 a)  C[1]];
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
```

Actually this is just to calculate this:

```
    y[x_] = Sqrt[-( k /x^2) + b/(3 a) + f*(x^(-3 a)) ];
    DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
```

The solution is look like this ??!!!

```
{{x[t] -> InverseFunction[Inactive[Integrate][1/(K[1] Sqrt[(
    K[1]^(-2 - 3 a) (3 a f K[1]^2 - 3 a k K[1]^(3 a) + b K[1]^(2 +    3 a)))/a]), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][t/Sqrt[3] + C[1]]}}
```

Comment: I get a solution to the second part in V13.0.1.  (Your second sentence, "I don't how to get some a solution...," is missing a word or two; I assumed you mean "I don't know how to get a solution..." — that is, that the second `DSolve` returns the input and not a solution.)

Comment: yes it was "know", can you show your result please

Comment: Not all integrals can be expressed in closed form. If you what solution try numeric with: `NDSolve` or:`ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: y[x_] = Sqrt[-( k /x^2) + b/(3 a) + f*(x^(-3 a)) ];
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]

Comment: this is my real function

Comment: There is some confusion here:  Mathematica is reporting the solution in an implicit integral form because it's can't integrate it.  Try this:  write the DE you have in terms of x(t).  Then replace x(t) with just x, then separate variables and apply the definite integral to both sides with limits x(t_0)=x_0 and x(t)=x(t).  You can't integrate it but the expression you get should be equivalent to the InverseFunction reported by Mathematica.

Comment: It's not giving any thing!!

Comment: What is not giving anything? You show `DSolve` gives `{{x[t] -> InverseFunction[Inactive[Integrate][1/(K[1]...`, which is the solution it finds. What  would you like to get? It's in terms of a (hyper)elliptic integral of indefinite genus, which cannot be integrated further. You could derive this solution by hand from your second part, and you'd get stuck in exactly the same place. So I don't think you will get any closer to an expression for the solution than this. But that does not mean the solution cannot be analyzed.

Comment: If we consider a,b,k and x are positive!!